How to install popper.js via composer?
I manage all my dependencies via composer. One of those dependencies is for twbs/bootstrap and composer was able to resolve that package. However, bootstrap depends on popper.js and so far I have had no luck finding popper.js version 2.11.8 or higher via composer. I don't want to maintain popper.js manually, but simply by calling composer update. Do you know of an alternative package name that can be used?

Why do you need bootstrap installed by composer? It's better to have frontend stuff separated (e.g. installed by npm and maintained there). Bootstrap in the end it's just a collection of html tags so you can put it in twig and still have everything working

If you use a package that has unresolved dependencies, please report this as a bug to the maintainers of that package

@NicoHaase: I reported this to the maintainer of twbs/bootstrap. Thanks for the suggestion.

I learned from the maintainer that bootstrap has integrated popper.js in the js module bootstrap.bundle.min.js. Just include this module in the body of your php file instead of bootstrap.min.js.
